# Django: Could not found exception in Traceback

Tags: python, django, nginx, python-requests, urllib3

I have facing some issue with python requests in a Django project. It only occur in 2nd requests.post().

Although It exited with exception `TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'`.
But after updating urllib3. There is no exception in traceback.

```
[2021-12-08 15:54:48 +0000] [11410] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:11439)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/project/api/views/a_view.py", line 765, in create_power_trace
    headers=power_trace_headers)
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 117, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1373, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 319, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 280, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 201, in handle_abort
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
```

For your information, my code is something like this:-

```
res1 = requests.post(url1, data=data1)
result = res1.json()
print(result['id'])   # successfully prints
data2 = {'id': result['id']}
res2 = requests.post(url2, data=data2)   # System exited
print(res2)
```

Above snippet works fine outside of my project (tested in a different script with same environment same instance).
And of course, no issue found in local.

Comment: Is this snippet supposed to take long? I suspect that your Gunicorn times out and exits directly (in this case, it won't show a HTTP-related exception)

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @jkoestinger. Thanks. You are correct. There was issue in Nginx configuration. Now it's working after adding server_name in nginx conf

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue was not caused by python or django.

Request lost for Nginx misconfiguration. I think my request hit the destination but reponse cannot came back to source as I forgot to add server_name in nginx conf.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).